`cargo package` fails saying warning: no `Cargo.toml` file found when packaging
Here is the full output:
PS C:\ox\ditrit\specimen\rust\writable> cargo package
warning: no `Cargo.toml` file found when packaging `specimen__writable` (note the case of the file name).
   Packaging specimen__writable v0.1.0 (C:\ox\ditrit\specimen\rust\writable)
   Verifying specimen__writable v0.1.0 (C:\ox\ditrit\specimen\rust\writable)
error: failed to verify package tarball

Caused by:
  failed to read `C:\ox\ditrit\specimen\rust\writable\target\package\specimen__writable-0.1.0\Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2)

Here is the content of specimen/rust/writable/Cargo.toml:
[package]
name = "specimen__writable"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"
license = "MPL-2.0"
description = "A helper type to help test the output writte to stdout by some code."
homepage = "https://github.com/ditrit/specimen"
repository = "https://github.com/ditrit/specimen"
readme = "../../README.md"

[lib]
name = "writable"
path = "writable.rs"

The repository containing the whole code is there: https://github.com/ditrit/specimen
What I want to do is to publish the specimen crate whose code is located in the rust folder, but as I have structured the project with sub-crates, it appears I must publish those first. I've prefixed all the sub-crates names with specimen__ because I don't want them to use up good, useful names in crates.io. Still, I fail to publish any crate of the project.
Please help me overcome the error produced by the cargo package command.

Multiple crates & sub-crates sounds a lot like a workspace (also in The Book) Creating one might solve your problems.

I did create one but this didn't affect the command outcome in any way.
